# Prometheus using multiple target

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

We need to monitor several of target with prometheus, when we have a short list of targets
it was not a problem to modify, however we need to add many targets (50-70 new targets) from diffrent clusters
My question if there is a more elegant way to achieve this
instead of using it like this

```
- job_name: blackbox-http # To get metrics about the exporter’s targets
  metrics_path: /probe
  params:
    module: [http_2xx]
  static_configs:
    - targets:
      - http://clusterA   
      - https://clusterA   
      - http://clusterB 
      - http://clusterC 
      - http://clusterC 
        ...
```

maybe to mount additional files for each cluster , I mean to provide a file with targets for clusterA only and new file for clusterB only etc, is it possible ?

And the same for jobs, mount each job from a file

Answer (score 1):

When you have a growing or variable list of targets the best way of managing the job definition is to use SRV records instead of static_configs.

With SRV records you only need to define a `dns_sd_config` with only one target that will be resolved using a DNS query, then you don't need to change the configuration every time you add a new target only add it on the DNS record

An example from the documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/blog/2015/06/01/advanced-service-discovery/#discovery-with-dns-srv-records) adapted to your question:

```
- job_name: 'myjob'
  metrics_path: /probe
  params:
    module: [http_2xx]
  dns_sd_configs:
  - names:
    - 'telemetry.http.srv.example.org'
    - 'telemetry.https.api.srv.example.org'
```

You can use an internal DNS service to generate those records, and if you have targets with `http` and `https` mixed you probably need to have two records because the SRV record defines the port to use.